# How to clear server side angularjs message using ngMessages module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement server-side validation for a form element using angularjs.

I followed this question (using the last answer to that question as the basis of solution).

[How to display server errors in Angularjs with ng-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157377/how-to-display-server-errors-in-angularjs-with-ng-messages)

And with help from this article: http://codetunes.com/2013/server-form-validation-with-angular/ - I'm trying to clear the error message using a directive after the value is changed.

The problem is, I don't know how to get a handle on the field to reset the validity on the input. The code below was essentially copied from the article but is not working with ng-messages module.

```
angular.module('OCS')
  .directive('serverError', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on('change', function (ev) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.$setValidity('server', true);
        })
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The code below reads the response from the server and displays the error messages. (this is working)

```
if (response.status === 400) {
    response.data.forEach(function(fieldMsg){
      form[fieldMsg.param].$setValidity('server', false);
      if (!$scope.formErrors){
        $scope.formErrors = {};
      }
      $translate('errors.' + fieldMsg.msg).then(function(msg){
        $scope.formErrors[fieldMsg.param] = msg;
      });
    });
```

And an example of the input:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="50">
        <label>{{'pages.profilePage.email' | translate}}</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="profileDetails.email" name="email" class="md-input md-input-white" required server-error>
        <div ng-messages="updateProfileForm.email.$error" ng-if='updateProfileForm.email.$dirty'>
            <div ng-messages-include="error-messages"></div>
            <div ng-message="server">{{formErrors.email}}</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

1. Displaying the server error works fine.
2. The directive is registered and fires.

Essentially, I need to execute something more like this from within the directive:

`form[element[0].name].$setValidity('server', true);`

But how can I get a reference to the `current form` from within the directive without knowing the form name?

---------------- Edited Here --------------

This is what I went with, I'm not sure if there's a better way to access the form from the directive:

```
angular.module('OCS')
  .directive('serverError', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.on('change', function (ev) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          if (scope.formErrors) {
            scope.formErrors[element[0].name] = undefined;

            var formName = element.parents('form').attr('name');
            scope[formName][element[0].name].$setValidity('server', true);
          }
        })
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You're using `$scope.formErrors` to store the errors, so you just need to remove the field from that. i.e. `delete $scope.formErrors['email'];`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already but it just removes the message, the field and form are still regarded as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the form name to your submit handler:

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="handleSubmit(form1)">..</form>
```

Then you can access the form via the parameter passed to your submit handler:

```
$scope.handleSubmit = function(form) {
    console.log(form.$name)
}
```

i.e.

```
form['input'].$setValidity('server', true);
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: this would probably work also if I pass the form name through the scope. But the edit I just posted is okay, it works. Cheers